# Input Chinese Characters in Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, insert-update

I am using PHP and is inserting chinese characters to MySQL from my system. I used the prefix N but I encountered some error. Here is my code.

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO BK (language, id, names) VALUES ('N':language'', ':id', 'N':names'')";
$stmtNew = $dbRemote->prepare($insert);  
$stmtNew->bindValue(':language', $Val['Language']);
$stmtNewL->bindValue(':id', $ID);
$stmtNewL->bindValue(':names', $langVal['Name']);
$stmtNewL->execute();
```

What could be my problem?

Comment: What is the error? also Is your colum or table character encoding (Collation) set to `utf8_*` or `utf8mb4_*` ?

Comment: How to set table into utf8mb4? I am not sure @Scuzzy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert chinese character in mysql table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265247/how-to-insert-chinese-character-in-mysql-table)

Comment: You really should Google before you ask, if you just Googled your question title, you would have found your answer.

Comment: @bleykFaust what is the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't insert Chinese character into MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456313/cant-insert-chinese-character-into-mysql)

Comment: @Scuzzy It shows an error on the last statement but I don't know why it happens

Comment: @bleykFaust I can't help you sorry unless you copy and paste the _exact error message_ returned by the failing function call.